# printing ActiveRecord::Associations array elements in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm trying to display a list of elements from an Associations array:

```
<%= Event.find_by_id(params[:id]).attendees.to_a.map do |att| %>
<%= att.name %>
<% end %>
```

the output in the browser is the following:

```
Attendee-name ["\n"]
```

How can I get rid of the ["\n"] or what is a better way of manipulating the Associations arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out, this should be what you are going for.

```
<% Event.find_by_id(params[:id]).attendees.each do |att| %>
  <%= att.name %>
<% end %>
```

Also `.chomp` is what you need to remove `\n` but try the above code first.

Answer (score 0):

It was a very stupid problem, this is the solution if anyone gets stuck on the same thing:

```
<% Event.find_by_id(params[:id]).attendees.to_a.map do |att| %>
<%= att.name %>
<% end %>
```

leaving the <%= on the first line was the cause of the problem.